# Android storeimage also creates thumbnail

Tags: android, image, insert, thumbnails

Android:

I am using following code to insert image into album

According to description this method insert image also creates its thumbnail i don't want thumbnail to be created how can i stop thumbnail creation ?

Problem is I write image in album but when i select image from album it returns the thumbnail image path which is not required.

### insert image parameters

Parameters

```
scr The content resolver to use
source  The stream to use for the image
title   The name of the image
description The description of the image


MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(contentResolver ,file.getAbsolutePath(),
    file.getName(), );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled with this as well. To get the actual image data location using the images resource URI:

```
        String dataColumnName = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA;
        Uri mediaUri = //Image's URI;


    if (mediaUri != null)
    {
        String[] proj = { dataColumnName };
        Cursor actualimagecursor = managedQuery(mediaUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int actual_image_column_index = actualimagecursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(dataColumnName);
        boolean hasValues = actualimagecursor.moveToFirst();

        if (hasValues)
        {
            //this is the file location of the image
            String path = actualimagecursor.getString(actual_image_column_index);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am already using this code and it returns the thumbnail image name

Comment: Are you testing this on the emulator or on a particular device?